# Pull first image from each JSON object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, tumblr

I'd like to loop through all posts given by the JSON object and pull the first image from each post. Here is [the Tumblr API Documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

At the moment I have this code which spits out all the content for the **first post only**. I would like it to spit out the **first image** from **all posts**.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/sjtest1.tumblr.com/posts?api_key={mykey}",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        console.log(results); 
        var postBody = results.response.posts[0].body;
        $(".x").html(postBody); 
    }
});
```

And this is Tumblr's example text post JSON object:

```
{
   "meta": {
      "status": 200,
      "msg": "OK"
   },
   "response": {
      "blog": { ... },
      "posts": [
         {
            "blog_name": "citriccomics",
            "id": 3507845453,
            "post_url": "http:\/\/citriccomics.tumblr.com\/post\/3507845453",
            "type": "text",
            "date": "2011-02-25 20:27:00 GMT",
            "timestamp": 1298665620,
            "state": "published",
            "format": "html",
            "reblog_key": "b0baQtsl",
            "tags": [
               "tumblrize",
               "milky dog",
               "mini comic"
            ],
            "note_count": 14,
            "title": "Milky Dog",
            "body": "<p><img src=\"http:\/\/media.tumblr.com\
               /tumblr_lh6x8d7LBB1qa6gy3.jpg\"\/><a href=\"http:\/\
               /citriccomics.com\/blog\/?p=487\" target=\"_blank\">TO READ
               THE REST CLICK HERE<\/a><br\/>\n\nMilky Dog was inspired by
               something <a href=\"http:\/\/gunadie.com\/naomi\"
               target=\"_blank\">Naomi Gee<\/a> wrote on twitter, I really
               liked the hash tag <a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/
               search?q=%23MILKYDOG\" target=\"_blank\">#milkydog<\/a>
               and quickly came up with a little comic about it. You can
               (and should) follow Naomi on twitter <a href=\"http:\/\
               /twitter.com\/ngun\" target=\"_blank\">@ngun<\/a> I'm on
               twitter as well <a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\
               /weflewairplanes\"target=\"_blank\">@weflewairplanes<\/a>
               <\/p>\n\nAlso, if youâ€™re a Reddit user (or even if
               you're not) I submitted this there, if you could up vote
               it I'd be super grateful just <a href=\"http:\/\
               /tinyurl.com\/5wj3tqz\" target=\"_blank\">CLICK HERE<\/a>"
         },
         ...
      ],
      "total_posts": 3
   }
}
```

As you can see, images in the `body` are wrapped with `<p>` tags.

Would anyone know how help pull the images?

Comment: What about posts that aren't of the type `text`?

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are already using jQuery, how about:

```
       $(results.response.posts[0].body).find('img').first();
```

It is probably not the best alternative, but it should do.

If you wanna do it for multiple posts:

```
            var img = [];
            $.each(results.response.posts, function (ix,el){
                 img.push($(el.body).find('img').first());
           })
```